Make Swagger UI display input endpoint parameters data types
When i use Swagger UI in my ASP .NET Core project, i can't see input parameters data types.
I use endpoint like this:
/// <summary>
/// SomeSummary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">SomeParameter description</param>
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async IActionResult GetAsync([Range(1, int.MaxValue)] [SwaggerParameter(Required = true)] int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}

While docs.json contains that field:
        "description": "SomeSummary",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "integer",  <--
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "description": "SomeParameter description",
            "x-position": 1,
            "format": "int32",
            "maximum": 2147483647.0,
            "minimum": 1.0,
            "nullable": false
          },

        ],


Is there some attribute to explicitly set parameter type or or make it so that it is automatically specified from docs.json?
I'm not sure i have specified swagger config file due to the fact i use library from NuGet.
To do it directly, i should use:
internal class DocCardsOperationProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        if (context.MethodInfo.Name == "GetAsync")
        {
            IList<OpenApiParameter> parameters = context.OperationDescription.Operation.Parameters;
            OpenApiParameter? id = parameters.FirstOrDefault(parameter => parameter.Name == "id");
            if (id is not null)
            {
                id.Schema = new()
                {
                    Type = NJsonSchema.JsonObjectType.Integer, Format = "int32"
                };
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

I dont find this way correct.
Thanks!

Does your docs.json contain "openapi": "3.x.x" or "swagger": "2.0"? What version of Swashbuckle do you use?

@Helen, thanks for the answer. I have there:
"x-generator": "NSwag v13.18.2.0 (NJsonSchema v10.8.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))",
  "openapi": "3.0.0",


Just added following code:
using NSwag;
using NSwag.Generation.Processors;
using NSwag.Generation.Processors.Contexts;

namespace SI.NonTrade.WebApi;

innal class DocCardsOperationProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
         IList<OpenApiParameter> apiParameters = context.OperationDescription.Operation.Parameters;
         foreach (OpenApiParameter apiParameter in apiParameters)
         {
             apiParameter.Schema = new()
             {
                 Type = apiParameter.Type,
                 Format = apiParameter.Format,
                 IsNullableRaw = apiParameter.IsNullableRaw
             };
         }

         return true;
    }

}


